# Android 6.0 - What is the difference between dangerous and special permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

As the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous) from google states out, there are *normal*, *dangerous* and special permissions.

Dangerous are, as far as I understand, disabled as default (is this true?).

> If an app declares that it needs a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly grant the permission to the app.

Does this infect also updates or only new installs?

And what exactly is the difference between the dangerous permission and 
the special permissions?

Android says for special permissions:

> **Special Permissions**
>   There are a couple of permissions that don't behave like normal and dangerous permissions. SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and WRITE_SETTINGS are particularly sensitive, so most apps should not use them. If an app needs one of these permissions, it must declare the permission in the manifest, *and* send an intent requesting the user's authorization. The system responds to the intent by showing a detailed management screen to the user.

Is that not the same like the quote above? I do not get the difference. 
Thanks!

Comment: When you request a dangerous permission on Android 6.0+, the user will be shown a **dialog** (triggered by calling `requestPermissions`) where he/she can grant or deny the app that permission. When you request `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW ` _"the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management **screen**"_ (triggered by sending an intent).

Comment: Ah ok, so Dialog/Screen and methodcall/intent. Do you have an explanation why the screen must be invoked by an intent? Why they are making a difference there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dangerous**

Basically Google decided to mark some permissions dangerous ([see full list here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous)). Those permissions need to be requested actively if you want to use them, so you can't just put them in the manifest and expect everything to work, it wont. But if the user gives access once, you can use that permission for the remainder of the applications life (unless the user goes in and clicks it off inside settings).

The request will open a dialog on top of your app where the user can decide if you are allowed the permission.

**Special**

Special are like dangerous, except even harder to use. In order to use special you have to start an intent requesting the permission so the user goes to a Google defined activity that manages everything.

This is how it works for apps targeting Android 6.0 and onward.

Comment: So...Are the dangerous permissions disabled as default, even for updates? What is the difference to special permissions?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re if you target android 6.0 yes they are disabled EVEN if they are in the manifest. You have to request it and the user has to give you access to use it.

Comment: I doubt a bit that you have to ask them every time. That would mean facebook would be forced to ask the user everytime they show the messenger bubble heads. Is this really the case? Or is FB just targeting a lower api lvl?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re Sorry I just reread, that is a mistake I'll fix right away.

Comment: _"Are the dangerous permissions disabled as default, even for updates?"_ If the user upgrades from an earlier version of the app that had a targetSdkVersion < 23, then the app would've been given the permission at install-time when it was originally installed, and so even though you've switched to the new permission model you won't have to request the permission again (unless the user goes into the Android settings menu and revokes your app's permissions).

Comment: @Warpzit: My comment was a statement, not a question.

Comment: @Michael It actually doesn't matter if they are moved over or not, any new users will get it so you should just write the code that handles it and it wont be an issue either way.

Answer (score 2):

System permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:

1. **Normal permissions** do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your
   app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the
   permission automatically.
2. **Dangerous permissions** can give the app access to the user's
   confidential data. If your app lists a normal permission in its
   manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you
   list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give
   approval to your app.

Ques : Dangerous are, as far as I understand, disabled as default (is this true?).
Ans : Yes **Dangerous permissions** will be disabled by default.

Ques : Does this infect also updates or only new installs?
Ans :  There are Two cases

Case 1 : App Targeting & running on API Level 23

If your app is targeting API Level 23, then all the permission which are defined in the `Android Manifest` will now ask for a permission when they need it.

For example, instead of giving an app access to your camera when you install it, you’ll be prompted the first time the app wants to access your camera.

Case 2 : App Designed for Older Version

Older Android apps automatically get these permissions when you install them, but you can revoke any permission you want from Settings >> Apps >> App >>App Info >> Permissions.

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: That's not really what the question is about, though.